# WMI Event Watcher Task namespace

Tags: events, namespaces, ssis, wmi

In SSIS 2008 what is the 'WMI namespace' when creating a new WMI connection manager? The tutorials that I have found keep assuming the local database and do nothing with the server name and WMI namespace. However, I  am connecting to a server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!